# Conflito entre Spring MVC e PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, spring-mvc

Estou com um problema para integrar o Spring MVC com o PrimeFaces. Parece que dá um conflito entre eles.

Tem a configuração no web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

o arquivo do faces-config.xml com o Spring

org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver

E mesmo assim não funcionou.

Já tentei [esse tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/primefaces-spring-hibernate-integration-example/) e o tutorial do Spring Web-flow que fala sobre o Spring-Faces e não funcionou.

O [código fonte quebrado com o problema encontra-se no Github](https://github.com/MarcelorjOliveira/AssessmentSystem).

Comment: Bom acho que você deve estar falando sobre o Spring e não o Sring-MVC pois o tutorial que você passou não trata do Spring-MVC, melhor que postar o código nesse caso seria você postar a saida do seu servidor de aplicação ou servlet (jboss,tomcat) e também postar o seu pom.xml para que os colegas possam te ajudar com mais precisão.
Poste também o faces-config.xml e o applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você comece seu projeto a partir de um arquétipo do Maven (como um dos dois que habilitam JSF + Spring desse [repositório](https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/maven-archetype-templates)). Se quiser algo ainda mais ágil pode tentar também o suporte a JSF do [Spring Roo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-jsf.html). Em ambos os casos o PrimeFaces vem pré-configurado para você.

É claro que não existe solução perfeita e você terá que fazer upgrade manual de algumas bibliotecas no primeiro caso (caso queira trabalhar com as versões mais recentes do Spring e do PrimeFaces) e / ou aprender um pouco sobre o Spring Roo no segundo. Porém esse trabalho tedioso de configuração é feito para ti.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal.
Muito obrigado Anthony por ter tentado me ajudar, mas percebi que não era exatamente isso que queria.

O que estava interessado em fazer está contido aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc

Obrigado